# Suddenly Glide is failing to get image from url

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide

Thanks for viewing my question here.

I am using Glide to fetch image from Firebase storage, basically i am using url to get the image from storage. First day it was working fine but suddenly it stopped fetching image. i did not touch the code. I have checked many answer but still i could not fix the issue. Please let me know where i am doing mistake.
This is gradle app file.

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
```

This is the Glide code i use in my Adapter java file

```
Glide.with(context).load(mproduct.get(position).getUrl()).into(viewHolder.pic);
```

Internet permission is there

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: try installing latest dependency of [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: Add latest version as well ... Still same issue...

Answer (score 2):

If it is not loading an image, there must be an error!

Check out the reason using listener:-

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(mproduct.get(position).getUrl())
    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            // Here you will get the cause of error...
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
            // do something
            return true;
         }
    })
    .into(viewHolder.pic);
```

Comment: @wizad as i mentioned early... when i implemented this. It was working well and fine...suddenly it stopped...

Answer (score -1):

Please try with Piccaso

You can try below code..

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(mproduct.get(position).getUrl()).error(R.drawable.demo_image).into(viewHolder.pic);
```

dont forget to add dependency for Piccasso.

Comment: Vote down reason: the question is talking about Glide.